# trouble with jquery template plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-templates

I have a grid on the page. When i clicking row- the item edit form with item data displayed inside dialog (jquery  dialog ui plugin).
The problem is to get data item from html with new user input, after dialog 'Save' button clicked.
here is my code:

```
$('#OutLookAccountsGrid').on('click', 'span.btnOutlookAccountEdit', function () {


    //getting data from grid row
    var account = $(this).tmplItem().data;
    //populating edit template with data
    var tbl = $('#outlookaccountEditFormTmpl').tmpl(account);

    //displaying edit form inside dialog
    tbl.dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                var $this = $(this);

                //PROBLEM!!! PROBLEM!!! PROBLEM!!!
                //want to get values from user, but instead getting old values
                //populated from grid row
                var data = $.tmplItem(this).data;

                //...
                //want to send tmplItem with new values throught ajax as data param
                //...

          }
        }
     })//end of dialog

})
```

is it possible to get object with new values?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question: jquery template have ability to bind data with html only in one way: from data to html, so changes in input will have no effect to data.
(There was some plugin called jquery.datalink that tried to link object to template but as far as i knew it doesnt working in current version of teplate plugin)
So the onlyway to get changes data after user inserted values into inputs is:

```
   $.tmplItem(this).data["UserName"] = $this.find('input.outlusernm').val();
```

wich will make change in the data oject